# Did I translate these right? Not sure at all

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I need to translate some questions for work and I could really use some feedback from someone who is more familiar with the language than I am.

Here they go...

1. Do you carry a US citizenship or a Green Card? / Tragen Sie eine US-Staatsbürgerschaft oder eine Green Card?
2. Were you born in the US territories? / Waren Sie auf US-Territorium geboren wurden?
3. Have you had a long stay in the US over the past 5 years? / Hatten Sie einen längeren Aufenthalt in den USA in den letzten 5 Jahren?"

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is not wrong, but the following sounds better:

```
Besitzen Sie die US-Staatsbürgerschaft oder eine Green Card?
```

or

```
Sind Sie im Besitz der US-Staatsbürgerschaft oder einer Green Card?
```

You could also say *eine US-Staatsbürgerschaft* instead of *die US-Staatsbürgerschaft*, but usually we go with definite articles when we're talking about citizenship (because there is only one per country).
You can also write *Green Card* as *Greencard* which would be more German.

The second sentence is wrong grammatically. You should say:

```
Wurden Sie auf US-Territorium geboren?
```

or

```
Wurden Sie auf US-amerikanischem Staatsgebiet geboren?
```

The third sentence is correct.

Comment: @Janek Bevendorff: Please consider not answering questions that are obviously off topic. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions

Comment: @chirlu follow-up is already in -.-

Comment: Well, I flagged the new question. I think one was okay and I had a bit of spare time for giving an answer. But more like this? Come on. -.-

Comment: "one was okay" -- OP probaly didn't even notice her question getting closed because she already had what she wanted. You basically educated her the wrong way around. Thorsten in her new question did the same, so now we have a) a very satisfied new user who b) will come back with more OT Qs and c) tell all her friends about how deSE offers free translation services, for what appears to be commercial or official grade texts.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.